# react native without expo how to force only light theme

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

React native is assembled via cli after building the apk and installing it on the device, when you switch the theme of the device, the theme of the application itself changes, which changes the text color in the textInput component to white and it turns out that white text is on a white background, the background color of some components also changes to gray , when changing the parent theme in the styles.xml file and making changes to androidManifest.xml, nothing changes, how to fix this I’m already going crazy!

Adding the line `AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);` in MainActivity.java also does not change the situation, also adding the line `<item name="android:forceDarkAllowed">false</item>` to styles.xml does not bring any changes

styles.xml:

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
        <item name="android:forceDarkAllowed">false</item>
        <!-- <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item> -->
    </style>
</resources>
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
   <resources>
       <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
           <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
           <item name="android:forceDarkAllowed">false</item>
           <!-- <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
           <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
           <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item> -->
        </style>
    </resources>
```

react-native 0.76
gradle: 8.0.1